# Can I make conditional statements with HTML tags in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a web scraping project. My data is from Wikipedia, [List of largest companies in the United States by revenue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_in_the_United_States_by_revenue). When I extract the data (the first table), I can't get the `revenue growth` column to reflect if it was positive or negative because it is depicted by green triangles pointing upwards and red triangles pointing downwards. Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_in_the_United_States_by_revenue'

source = requests.get(url)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html')

table = soup.find_all('table', class_='wikitable sortable')[0]

table_data = table.find_all('tr')[1:]

table_df = []  
for row in table_data:  
    row_data = row.find_all('td')  
    row_df = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]

    table_df.append(row_df)

table_df
```

How can I get `revenue growth` to show `+` or `-`?

```
table_df = []  
for row in table_data:  
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    row_df = [data.text.strip() for data in row_data]
    if row_data.find_all('img', alt='Decrease') == True:
        row_df[4] = '-' + row_df[4]
    
    table_df.append(row_df)

table_df
```

Tried this code and it resulted in the same output as the original code

Comment: The image is in a `<span title="Increase">` or `<span title="Decrease">`. So you can look for these.

Comment: `find_all()` doesn't return `True` or `False`, it returns a list of all the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Barmar you could use the title attribute of the `<span>` that is holding the `<img>` to select the specific column and modify its content.

One approache would be to use [`replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree) to add the character corresponding to the image / title:

```
for t in soup.select('td:has(span[title])'):
    if t.span.span.get('title') == 'Increase':
        t.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f'<td>- {t.get_text(strip=True)}</td>','html.parser'))
    else:
        t.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f'<td>+ {t.get_text(strip=True)}</td>','html.parser'))
```

Following the little preprocessing you could scrape the table with `pandas.read_html()`

```
pd.read_html(str(soup))[1]
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_in_the_United_States_by_revenue'

source = requests.get(url)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html')


for t in soup.select('td:has(span[title])'):
    if t.span.span.get('title') == 'Increase':
        t.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f'<td>- {t.get_text(strip=True)}</td>','html.parser'))
    else:
        t.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(f'<td>+ {t.get_text(strip=True)}</td>','html.parser'))

pd.read_html(str(soup))[1]
```

|  | Rank | Name | Industry | Revenue (USD millions) | Revenue growth | Employees | Headquarters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Walmart | Retail | 611289 | - 6.7% | 2100000 | Bentonville, Arkansas |
| 1 | 2 | Amazon | Retail and cloud computing | 513983 | - 9.4% | 1540000 | Seattle, Washington |
| 2 | 3 | ExxonMobil | Petroleum industry | 413680 | - 44.8% | 62000 | Spring, Texas |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 96 | 97 | Bristol-Myers Squibb | Pharmaceutical industry | 46159 | + 0.5% | 34300 | New York City, New York |
| 97 | 98 | United Airlines | Airline | 44955 | - 82.5% | 92795 | Chicago, Illinois |
| 98 | 99 | Thermo Fisher Scientific | Laboratory instruments | 44915 | - 14.5% | 130000 | Waltham, Massachusetts |
| 99 | 100 | Qualcomm | Technology | 44200 | - 31.7% | 51000 | San Diego, California |